# Why does VS 2012 restart after a normal shutdown

Tags: visual-studio

At some point recently VS2012 started restarting after I use the normal shutdown (Exit from the File Menu).  It is irritating to say the least and I usually have to stop the restart via the Task Manager.

I assume that something has changed in my setup.  Search on StackOverflow and generally does not bring up any hits for this problem.

Comment: Do you have any extensions installed? How do you run the VS?

Comment: Yes - quite a lot so I suppose it could be one of those.  I am not sure what you mean by how I run it.  Double click the icon on the desk top.  I don't run as admin

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First try to run the VS in [safe mode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms241278%28v=vs.80%29.aspx).

If it exits OK try to disable some of the extensions. The most sprawling ones first (chance that some small utility would cause this is low).

I had massive issues even with some of the most popular extensions from the VS gallery (eg. CodeMaid). If you have many installed, it might also be some for of conflict.

Another option is to try to fix installation using the VS setup - or completely reinstall it.

Comment: OK - My biggest is probably ReSharper!